# I draw a rectangle or any shape by connecting lines in scenekit, how can i convert itinto SCNNode or apply texture only within specified shape

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I have a scenario where i need to draw custom shape(4,5,6 corners shape) on floor(horizontal plane), once shape is completed i need to apply texture within this shape in scenekit so that user can see applied texture only within shape.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of info here - so I'm going to take a wag to see if we can get you moving... assuming that you have created a mechanism to gather your 4,5,6 corners and know the actual "screen" coordinates, then you have enough information to create an SCNShape from a Bezier path (if you have an odd shape): use this post: 28190604 to create an skin it.  Putting it in the right place is tricky and you may have rotation issues to deal with.  I've gotten it pretty close in the past, but what you need might be different.

If it's just dragging to get close and a snap to affect to fit a known size, then create your shapes in advance and it's mostly a "get close", figure out the right shape, and drop it in type deal.

Comment: Can you please help me with any git source or help me with code? i'm searching but couldn't find how we can draw custom shapes and whenever we connect last point with the first one and its become a closed shape, now i want to place a texture or floor only between closed shape.

Comment: In the post I sent you, it explains how to close the shape, then lower it shows how to add some materials to it.  I'm assuming (but have not tried) to "texture map" a custom shape, but if you can add color, I don't see why you can't use a jpg.  It's usually just replacing a color with a picture using materials.